# Why mysql matching rows don't update?

Tags: mysql

For some reasons it seems that the rows are not being updated. Any idea why this would happen ?

```
UPDATE hts SET assigned='1' AND Owner='ms' WHERE hid='217477'
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.16 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0
```

`select assigned, Owner from hts where hid='217477';`

```
+----------+-------+
| assigned | Owner |
+----------+-------+
|     NULL | NULL  |
+----------+-------+
```

Show columns from hts

```
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| hid        | varchar(25)  | YES  | UNI | NULL    |       |
| assigned   | int(11)      | NO   |     | 0       |       |
| Owner      | varchar(10)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Comment: @EndeNeu Uhm, no it's not.  It's returning a row of `NULL` values, but that's still a row.

Comment: you don't have a record where hid = 217477, hence there is no update

Comment: remove the quotes from the hid then?

Comment: @EndeNeu But there is -- it just has `NULL` values for those columns.  (See also "Rows matched: 1")

Comment: Ahh sorry, I'll delete my comments, you are right, my bad, I really got to take a break from SO.

Comment: how about you show us the row then that you are trying to update.. aka the hid and anything else in there.

Comment: I agree with @JohnRuddell, run this `select * from hts where hid='217477';`

Comment: The gut reaction is to say that 0 rows affected means 1 of 2 things, 1: The row does not exist, or 2: The changes you're making aren't different.  So if you're running your select statement, then it's cached some how.

Comment: @AlanAsher or the OP has an `AND` between his `SET` columns instead of a comma :)

Comment: I thought that made a difference, but I tried it on my machine and set some fields to '' blank string and they updated with 0 so I didn't think to pursue that as the reason any more. But thanks for the update @JohnRuddell

Answer (score 3, accepted):

two things you can try..

first try removing the AND from the SET.. usually you do that with a comma..

```
UPDATE hts SET assigned=1, Owner='ms' WHERE hid='217477'
```

second try removing the quotes form the `hid` if it is an INT and not a VARCHAR

```
UPDATE hts SET assigned=1, Owner='ms' WHERE hid=217477
```

not sure why you are storing integers as strings.. **when in doubt you should ALWAYS store data by its intended datatype.**

**RECOMMENDATION:** change the datatypes if they are varchar to int. your update would look like this.

```
UPDATE hts SET assigned=1, Owner='ms' WHERE hid=217477
```

assigned should be integer as well as hid

Comment: indeed , it was the "AND" keyword... it's always easy to get it wrong.

Comment: @hey ok cool, glad it was a simple fix :) you should really look into storing the numbers as their corresponding datatype and not string for the future :) it'll make it more manageable and scalable down the road

Comment: @hey thanks for posting the table schema! since the datatype for assigned is int i removed the quotes from assigned in the SET, just as a FYI :)

Comment: thanks for the advice. The data is crawled from the internet so I didn't really want to take the risk to use int

Comment: @hey well you could ensure its int by checking and or casting to int in another programming language but i understand :)